# Unable to load the address! issue while working with Phantomjs 2.1

Tags: javascript, ssl, amazon-ec2, phantomjs

I am having phantomjs 2.1.1 for screen capture scenario in my Rails application.
This is my js:

```
var page = new WebPage(),
    address, output, actual_height;
var system = require('system');
if (system.args.length < 2 || system.args.length > 3) {
    phantom.exit();
} else {
    console.log('Else');
    address = system.args[1];
    output = system.args[2];
    console.log(address);
    console.log(output);
    page.viewportSize = { width: 1024, height: 768 };

    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        } else {
            console.log('Success...');
            /* Some code here */
        }
    });
}
```

I am facing this error while running the application in command line:

```
(cd /var/www/html/project/MyProject/vendor/javascripts/phantomjs_linux/bin; ./phantomjs /var/www/html/project/MyProject/vendor/javascripts/indicator_screenshots.js http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/users/1/reports/50148 /var/www/html/project/MyProject/public/indicator_screenshots/50148.png)
```

It is showing this error:

> Unable to load the address!

So through some R & D, I run the command from my bin folder as:

```
./phantomjs --debug=yes --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any --web-security=true /var/www/html/project/MyProject/vendor/javascripts/indicator_screenshots.js http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/users/1/reports/50148 /var/www/html/project/MyProject/public/indicator_screenshots/50148.png
```

This is my log:

> 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG] CookieJar - Created but will not store
>   cookies (use option '--cookies-file=' to enable persistent
>   cookie storage) 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG] Set  "http"  proxy to:  ""
>   : 1080 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG] Phantom - execute: Configuration
>   2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]      0 objectName : "" 2016-10-12T06:29:38
>   [DEBUG]
>   1 cookiesFile : "" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   2 diskCacheEnabled : "false" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   3 maxDiskCacheSize : "-1" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   4 diskCachePath : "" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   5 ignoreSslErrors : "true" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   6 localUrlAccessEnabled : "true" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   7 localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled : "false" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   8 outputEncoding : "UTF-8" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   9 proxyType : "http" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   10 proxy : ":1080" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   11 proxyAuth : ":" 
>   12 scriptEncoding : "UTF-8" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   13 webSecurityEnabled : "true" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   14 offlineStoragePath : "" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   15 localStoragePath : "" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   16 localStorageDefaultQuota : "-1" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   17 offlineStorageDefaultQuota : "-1" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   18 printDebugMessages : "true" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   19 javascriptCanOpenWindows : "true" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   20 javascriptCanCloseWindows : "true" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   21 sslProtocol : "any" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   22 sslCiphers :
>   "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5"
>   2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   23 sslCertificatesPath : "" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   24 sslClientCertificateFile : "" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   25 sslClientKeyFile : "" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   26 sslClientKeyPassphrase : "" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   27 webdriver : ":" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   28 webdriverLogFile : "" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   29 webdriverLogLevel : "INFO" 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   30 webdriverSeleniumGridHub : ""
>   2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG] Phantom - execute: Script & Arguments
>   2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]      script:
>   "/var/www/html/project/MyProject/vendor/javascripts/indicator_screenshots.js"
>   2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]      0 arg:
>   "http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/users/1/reports/50148" 2016-10-12T06:29:38
>   [DEBUG]      1 arg:
>   "/var/www/html/project/MyProject/public/indicator_screenshots/50148.png"
>   2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG] Phantom - execute: Starting normal mode
>   2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG] WebPage - setupFrame ""
>   2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG] FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/fs.js"
>   QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r"))) 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG]
>   FileSystem - _open: ":/modules/system.js" QMap(("mode",
>   QVariant(QString, "r"))) 2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG] FileSystem -
>   _open: ":/modules/webpage.js" QMap(("mode", QVariant(QString, "r"))) 
>   **Else** 
>   **http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/users/1/reports/50148**
>   **/var/www/html/project/MyProject/public/indicator_screenshots/50148.png**
>   2016-10-12T06:29:38 [DEBUG] WebPage - updateLoadingProgress: 10
>   2016-10-12T06:30:38 [DEBUG] Network - Resource request error:
>   QNetworkReply::NetworkError(TimeoutError) ( "Socket operation timed
>   out" ) URL: "http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/users/1/reports/50148"

You can see the address and output values in the above log after **Else**(in bold) which are written in js as console.log.
According to log, I am facing error at **page.open**.
Please help how to fix this issue..

Comment: did you try to `curl` to test the site is up?

Comment: The docs say you create a new page object by requiring 'webpage' and calling create on the interface object, not new-ing up anything, so maybe that's your problem: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/open.html